# Confuse about Hist default function in matlab

Tags: matlab

For example i have an image matrix that looks like this one:

```
1 2 3
1 5 6
1 5 3
```

Assume that my intensity goes from 1 to 6, so I need to produce something like an array:

```
1 : 3
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 0
5 : 2
6 : 1
```

I tried using hist function of matlab but it produced something looks really weried to me.
Can anybosy help me on that? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you probably haven't specified the correct histogram bins for `hist` (by default it creates 10 equally spaced bins). If you're interested in a simple histogram count, consider using [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
vals = 1:max(A(:));
count = histc(A(:), vals);
```

where `A` is your image matrix. `vals` is the first column in your desired output array, and `count` is the the second.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to linearize the image matrix using the colon operator, like in `hist(a(:))`. Calling `hist(a)` when `a` is a matrix will compute the histogram of each column.